# DateTime Backwards

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

With `select * from table`, a `datetime` column returns the value `2019-02-28 20:11:38.980`

with `select * from TableName where CreatedOn = '2019-28-02 20:11:38.980'` no erros (1 row affected)

with `select * from TableName where CreatedOn = '2019-02-28 20:11:38.980'` The conversion of a `varchar` data type to a `datetime` data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Why are the result `datetime` and the input `datetime` in different formats?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v18.2 if it makes any difference.

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. Formats apply **only** when a date is formatted as a string for display, or a string is parsed into a date type. What you assume for a `YYYY-MM-DD` format is simply the way the *client tool* displays dates.

Comment: If you have a problem with a query post it in the question itself. You may have used the wrong *string literal* to represent the date, or the data may *not* contain any row that matches what you want to find

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos stated, we need to see your query and dates have no format. [As you can see](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=faf8cc46ca6afbae9afb326c8b9569c1) if you are querying it for that specific value, and it exists, it wouldn't matter if it was a `datetime` or `varchar`. So, create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we may help.

Comment: Does the query nothing return, or do you get an error? Depending on your language, the literal string `'2019-02-28 20:11:38.980'` could be read as the 2nd day of the 28th month with the `datetime` datatype.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rmCLbA5UwYWPuQhnBF3oES/0

Comment: The OP is using SQL Server, @dewey

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the hint, misread that. Then this should work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f86a0/9/0

Comment: I believe the short answer is that SSMS always outputs in a fixed, pseudo-ISO8601 format and that apparently doesn't match your current `dateformat` setting. As you're in Germany I'm curious to know what your setting is.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is getting confused by the order of the month and day values in the string literals.  Dates and times have no format in the database.  However, the interpretation of string literals and the output of dates as string literals depends on user options for date order and language.

You can find the current session's date format and language settings by running the query below and looking for "dateformat" and "language":

```
dbcc useroptions
```

You can also get the language assigned to your session via this query:

```
select @@language;
```

To avoid regional date/time issues when specifying a string literal that represents a combined date and time value, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss".  The "T" is a literal character.

For example:

```
select convert(datetime, '2019-02-28T20:11:38.980');
```

According to the [String Literal Date and Time Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms180878(v=sql.105)#StringLiteralDateandTimeFormats) section in Microsoft's docs, the standard ANSI Standard SQL date format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" is supposed to be "multi-language". However, it does not work in all SQL languages (Danish, for example).

Comment: Thank you for your help.
 
With dbcc useroptions, the language is Deutsch and the dateformat is dmy

In addition, with select @@language the result is Deutsch.

With the string literal, everything is perfect with the query.

Now to work out how to set the output to a ISO 8601